How to create a Mercurial alias that lists diffs between two dates on the default branch for a number of files
We are migrating from CVS to Mercurial, and my job is to create aliases that do CVS-like actions in Mercurial. I have aliases for most of the commands, except for cvs diff -D <date1> -D <date2> <list of files> . I need a mercurial alias that looks like hg diffdates <date1> <date2> <list of files> and provides a difference between the two revisions if checked out on the default branch between those two dates.
The obvious alias
diffdates = diff --from $1 --to $2
Doesn't work. If we have two branches:
*    [revision 4] 2024-08-20 (default branch)
| *  [revision 3] 2024-08-18 (dev branch)
* |  [revision 2] 2024-08-16 (default branch)
|/
*    [revision 1] 2024-08-14 (default branch)

Then running hg diff --from 2024-08-19 --to 2024-08-21 a.txt b.txt will find the differences between revision 3 and revision 4 - even though revision 3 is not on the default branch. We want the differences between revision 2 and revision 4.
We have worked around this by using shell aliases for similar commands, so the next attempt was this:
diffdates = !$HG diff --from $($HG log -b default -d "<$1" --template "{node}\n" | head -1) --to $($HG log -b default -d "<$2" --template "{node}\n" | head -1)
This almost works, except that since only $1 and $2 are mentioned in the alias, Mercurial automatically ignores any future arguments. That is: running hg diffdates 2024-08-19 2024-08-21 a.txt b.txt will find the differences for all files between revisions 2 and 4.
Unfortunately Mercurial processes the $1, $2, $3 (etc) arguments before passing it into the shell command, so this alias doesn't work
diffdates = !$HG diff --from $($HG log -b default -d "<$1" --template "{node}\n" | head -1) --to $($HG log -b default -d "<$2" --template "{node}\n" | head -1) ${@:2}
(If Mercurial would let us interpret ${@:2} as 'a list of all arguments after the first two', then I wouldn't have to ask this question)
This is my most recent attempt, and it also doesn't work:
diffdates = !if [[ "$23" ]]; then echo "diffdates does not support more than 20 files or directories"; exit 1; else $HG diff --from $($HG log -b default -d "<$1" --template "{node}\n" | head -1) --to $($HG log -b default -d "<$2" --template "{node}\n" | head -1) "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9" "$10" "$11" "$12" "$13" "$14" "$15" "$16" "$17" "$18" "$19" "$20" "$21" "$22"; fi;
hg diff --from <rev> --to <rev> "<file>" "" actually gets all diffs from the current working directory, as well as <file> , so I need to unquote all of those arguments - which means that it won't work if there are spaces in the filenames. I could use a lot of nested "if; then; elsif; fi;" blocks, but that just becomes ridiculous
Is there a better way?

I think you can call a bash script file from the alias.

Yes, that works too. However it means that we need to modify two files (/etc/mercurial/hgrc , and the new bash script that runs the code), which doubles the work each developer needs to do.
